# XAML-Creating a TimePicker with TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datepicker

While working on my Wpf project, I need to make a time picker (a simple textbox with a separator on which the user can write `HH:mm:ss`).
I already did one, but the problem is that the separators are labels (:) in my textbox background style so I have to `TextBox.Text.PadRight` to simulate the separator thing and creates some bugs when getting the text.

Dashes will be replaced by the numbers. And after 2 and 4 input numbers it jumps the separator properly.

Edit : I need exactly the input type=“time” html control but don’t know how to implement it in WPF.

XAML Style

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxScheduleTime" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="27"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Border}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gainsboro"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="/AsyncBot;component/Fonts/#Open Sans"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11"/>
    <Setter Property="FontStretch" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="CaretBrush" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="MaxLines" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="contentborder"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="border"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Margin="33,0,0,0"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="45"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="22"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="22"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        
                        <Image Grid.Column="0"
                               Margin="3,0,0,0"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Source="/Images/Icons/schedule_white_24dp.png"
                               Width="20"
                               Height="20"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1"
                               x:Name="firstdbpt"
                               Content=":"
                               FontFamily="/AsyncBot;component/Fonts/#Open Sans"
                               FontSize="11"
                               Foreground="Gainsboro"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="2"
                               x:Name="sddbpt"
                               Content=":"
                               FontFamily="/AsyncBot;component/Fonts/#Open Sans"
                               FontSize="11"
                               Foreground="Gainsboro"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                        
                    </Grid>
                    
                    
                </Grid>




                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="contentborder" Value="0.56"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="contentborder" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="contentborder" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Focus.Border}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true"/>
                <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
        </MultiTrigger>

    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

> Access And Sort to time format

```
        private void TextBoxScheduleTime_LostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {


        string scheduletime = String.Concat(TextBoxScheduleTime.Text.Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)));
        scheduletime = scheduletime.Insert(2, ":");
        scheduletime = scheduletime.Insert(4, ":");


        Console.WriteLine(scheduletime);

    }
```

Image of what I need (ignore the black spot):
[image: Image of what I need]

Comment: Can you give an image of what you have now as well (minus the "`PadRight` simulation")? A before and after comparison would help us understand the issue.

Comment: Yes of course man ! Here's the link since I don't know how to reply with images. https://imgur.com/a/gCJrUHg

Comment: Thanks, typically you'd want to [edit] your question and paste it directly into the post. Good comments try to improve/critique a post and, most often, you'll want to "reply" by updating your question/answer where you think necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly but you can subscribe to the PreviewTextInput event of the textbox and count the number of characters to insert ":".

```
        private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
            if (textBox.Text.Length is 2 or 5)
            {
                textBox.Text += ":";
                textBox.CaretIndex = textBox.Text.Length;
            }
        }
```

otherwise you can use the [Extended WPF Toolkit™](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit) which contains a TimePicker control.
[image]

Comment: Yeah I already test this solution but it creates lot of bugs when I try to go back and mofidy a certain number. I solve my problem by creating a custom textbox with indications for the user in the background. It's not solved but it do the work ! Thanks man !